Прошу помочь найти ошибку в циклах и оптимизировать код
"Поступает запрос на одно число (n) диапазон только от 3-20, 

и код должен на поступившее число подобрать пары чисел
кратные числу (n). Пример: 9 - число из первой вставки
1218273645 - нужный пароль (1 и 2, 1 и 8, 2 и 7, 3 и 6, 4
и 5 - пары; число 9 кратно сумме каждой пары)"
def get_input():
        num = []
        number = int(input('Введите число от 3х до 20ти: '))
        if 3 <= number <= 20:
            num.append(number)
        else:
            print(f'Не верное число: {number}')
        return num
    
    
    def get_shifr(n):
        list1 = []
        list2 = []
        for i in n:
            for j in range(1, n):
                if i == j:
                    continue
                elif str([j, i]) in list1:
                    continue
                elif i % (i + j) == 0:
                    list2 += str(i) + str(j)
                    list1.append([i, j])
        return list2
    
    
    mum = get_input()
    print(get_shifr(mum))


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Добавьте в вопрос описание задачи. Что должен делать код?

Поступает запрос на одно число (n) диапазон только от 3-20, и код должен на поступившее число подобрать пары чисел кратные числу (n). Пример: 9 - число из первой вставки
1218273645 - нужный пароль (1 и 2, 1 и 8, 2 и 7, 3 и 6, 4 и 5 - пары; число 9 кратно сумме каждой пары)

А зачем тут приведение к строке? elif str([j, i]) in list1: В список то вы добавляете без такого приведения list1.append([i, j]). Конечно, в списке это потом уже не найдётся. Ищутся только однотипные вещи.

заголовок вопроса должен быть кратким и отражать его суть. зачем вы в заголовке целые сочинения пишите?

"Прошу помочь найти ошибку и дополнить код!" — какая ошибка-то? Или вы предлагаете нам самим её вычленить?

Вижу, ошибка спряталась у вас в коде

Минуснул и я. Не за длину задачи, а за невероятное умение её объяснить. Было б лучше, если бы просто переписали задачу из задания, а не пытались рассказать её своими словами.

Благодарю за ответы, вопрос решен, не судите строго я только учусь и здесь впервые. В дальнейшем буду более конкретнее описывать ситуацию.

Вам не надо в первой функции добавлять вводимое число в список. Вам надо просто оставить проверку на диапазон. Например, вот так:
def get_input():
    number = int(input('Введите число от 3х до 20ти: '))
    if 3 <= number <= 20:
        return number
    return None

Функция вернет введенное число если оно попадает в диапазон и вернет None если число вне диапазона.
Ошибка во второй функции возникает именно из-за того, что в строке
for j in range(1, n)

ожидается число в качестве второго аргумента, Вы же передаете список.
Изменим список на число, соответственно изменим диапазоны двух циклов, избавимся от вспомагательных списков и соберем строку из подходящих пар.
Дальше останется вызвать обе функции, не забыв сообщить о правильности ввода.
def get_input():
    number = int(input('Введите число от 3х до 20ти: '))
    if 3 <= number <= 20:
        return number
    return None


def get_shifr(n):
    out = ''
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            if n % (i + j) == 0:
                out += str(i) + str(j)
    return out


if mum := get_input():
    print(get_shifr(mum))
else:
    print(f'Не верное число: {mum}')

Есть один вопрос - является ли валидной пара из двух одинаковых чисел, например, при вводе четного числа, две половины этого числа будут валидны или нет? Код выше подразумевает, что да, будут. Если это не так, то диапазон второго цикла надо заменить:
for j in range(i+1, n):

